# Conditional Probability Given at least

Tags: probability

The probability that a certain mechanical component fails when first used is 0.05. If the component does not fail immediately, the probability it will function correctly for at least one year is 0.98. What is the probability that a new component functions correctly for at least one year?

Anyone know how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability that it does not immediately fail is $0.95$. **Given** that it does not immediately fail, the probability it lives at least a year is $0.98$. Therefore the probability it does not fail immediately, **and** then survives at least a year, is $\dots$.

**Remark:** Let $A$ and $B$ be events. Write $\Pr(B|A)$ for the conditional probability of $B$ given that $A$ has happened. Note that in general 
$\Pr(B|A)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}$, and therefore $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B|A)\Pr(A)$.

Comment: Why is it P(A and B) instead of P(A)?

Comment: Let A be the event "the person chosen is a man" and let $B$ be the event "the person chosen is bald." Suppose that $\Pr(A)=0.48$ and $\Pr(B|A)=0.30$. To find the probability that the person chosen is a bald man, (man and bald) we multiply $0.48$ by $0.3$.

Comment: What would be P(A) in words in relation to my example?

Comment: $0.95$, the probability the machine survives the shock of birth.

Comment: How about P(B)?

Comment: $B$ is the event the machine is alive a year from now. In *this example*, $A\cap B=B$, because $A\subseteq B$.  So $\Pr(B)=(0.95)(0.98)$. However, the formula I gave in the comment applies also to situations when $A\cap B\ne B$. The problem can be solved without the formula, indeed it is basically solved in the part before the Remark.

Comment: This is really confusing, then P(B) would make sense as well?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense, in this particular case. But we would have to observe that $A\cap B=B$ to make explicit use of the formula. Perhaps it is better at this stage if you don't use the formula (you will undoubtedly need it later). So let us argue very informally. About $950$ of $1000$ machines survive being turned on. About $98\%$ of these live at least a year. That's about $(950)(98)=931$, so our probability is $931/1000$.

Comment: Another way: What percentage of machines are scrapped before a year has elapsed? $5\%$ are scrapped immediately. $2\%$ of the $95\%$ that survive birth are dead before a year. That's about $1.9\%$. So the probability of being scrapped in a year or less is $6.9\%$, and therefore the probability of being alive is $93.1\%$.